# How can I make CSS affect DOM elements generated after the CSS was interpreted?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="myTable">
    </table>
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script src="logic.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this CSS code:

```
#myTable {
    table-layout: fixed;
    border: solid 1px;
}
```

As you can see, the document has an empty table. The content for that table (the rows and columns) is generated by the JavaScript code, linked at the end of the document.

When I open the document, the border described in the CSS appears around the table, but not between the generated cells.

I *assume* that the reason for this is because the CSS is linked to at the beginning of the document, in the `<head>`, while the JavaScript code that generates the rows and columns runs at the end of the document.

I (think) I understand the reason for this problem, but I'm not sure how to fix this. How can I make the CSS apply to DOM elements generated later in the document?

Comment: Probably because you could have found a solution on Google in 10 seconds so no research effort was shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your code. You are putting a border around your table. You might want to include border style rules on your `td`'s to achieve your desired result.

```
#myTable {
    table-layout    : fixed;
    border          : 1px solid black;
    border-collapse : collapse; /* Add this */
}

#myTable td {
    border : 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: So you don't have side-by-side borders for your cells and table edges, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the `td` style.

```
#myTable {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

#myTable, #myTable td{
    border: solid 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your css is being applied correctly and in the right order. As has been noted you are calling for a border on your table in your css file.